# A* algorithm change node parent

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation, a-star

I am confused about changing the parent of a node in the A* algorithm.
There seem to be different ways of choosing a new parent:

In this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNXfSOx4eEE

It says that you should check this:

```
 G cost currentNode + movement cost from currentNode <= G cost openListNode
```

If that is the case then we should replace the parent node of the openListNode to the current node.

But in this implementation:
http://www.codebytes.in/2015/02/a-shortest-path-finding-algorithm.html

it has the following code:

```
static void checkAndUpdateCost(Cell current, Cell t, int cost){
    if(t == null || closed[t.i][t.j])return;
    int t_final_cost = t.heuristicCost+cost;

    boolean inOpen = open.contains(t);
    if(!inOpen || t_final_cost<t.finalCost){
        t.finalCost = t_final_cost;
        t.parent = current;
        if(!inOpen)open.add(t);
    }
}
```

It checks the final cost which is : G + H , which contradicts the other explanation, as it should be only G cost, not the sum of the G cost and the heuristic.

Can someone explain me, which one is correct ?, is the implementation wrong ?

Comment: I think both are saying the same, but they are using differents words. The implementation looks right. I can provide  my own A* implementation to another problem (8-puzzle): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106659/java-using-a-algorithm-to-solve-8-puzzle-boards-board-data-type-works-fine/31117077#31117077

Comment: In any case, you should not take the heuristic into your calculation when updating the parent. The heuristic value is only used for determining which node to choose next.

Comment: @Koekje so the implementation would be wrong right ?, In most of the explanations I saw, you only check the "G" cost, not the "H", at least not for changing a node parent.

Comment: Glancing over it, it seems like you are correct yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bottom Line Up Front (BLUF):**

The video is accurate, but here's the key: The node's parent should only be updated in one of the following two cases: 1.) when encountering the node for the first time, or 2.) when you find a more efficient path to a node that was previously encountered. Also, do not use the heuristic when updating a node's parent.

**Additional Details:**

Below is a working implementation based on [Wikipedia's Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode); I've added extra comments to differentiate the two cases.

If `!isOpen && !isClosed` is `true` then the node has never been seen before; therefore, it's parent should be set to the current node, and it should be added to the open set. But if `!isOpen && !isClosed` is `false`, then the node was already in the open set (i.e. if `isOpen` is true) or if it was previously closed (i.e. if `isClosed` is true). Therefore, we need to check if the current path is more efficient than the one which previously caused the neighbor node to be in the open/closed set-- this is why we check if `costFromStart <  g_score[neighborNode.x][neighborNode.y]`

```
while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
    Pair node = openList.dequeueMin().getValue();

    if (node.equals(goal)) {
        // construct the path from start to goal
        return reconstruct_path(goal);
    }

    for (Pair neighborNode : getNeighbors(node,goal)) {
        if (neighborNode == null) continue;
        boolean isOpen = openSet.contains(neighborNode);
        boolean isClosed = closedSet.contains(neighborNode);
        double costFromStart = g_score[node.x][node.y]+MOVEMENT_COST;

        // check if the neighbor node has not been
        // traversed or if a shorter path to this
        // neighbor node is found.
        if (
            (!isOpen && !isClosed) // first time node has been encountered
                || //or
            costFromStart < g_score[neighborNode.x][neighborNode.y]) //new path is more efficient
        {
            came_from[neighborNode.x][neighborNode.y] = node;
            g_score[neighborNode.x][neighborNode.y] = costFromStart;
            h_score[neighborNode.x][neighborNode.y] =
                    estimateCost(neighborNode,goal);
            if (isClosed) {
                closedSet.remove(neighborNode);
            }
            if (!isOpen) {
                openList.enqueue(neighborNode,costFromStart);
                openSet.add(neighborNode);
            }
        }
    }
    closedSet.add(node);
}
```